# How to adjust transparency (alpha) in seaborn pairplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I can create beatiful scatter plot with seaborns `regplot`, obtain the right level of transparency through the `scatter_kws` as in

```
sns.regplot(x='logAssets', y='logLTIFR', lowess=True, data=df, scatter_kws={'alpha':0.15}, line_kws={'color': 'red'})
```

and obtain this:

[image]

Is there an option in a seaborn `pairplot` to tweak transparency?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Ok I was very close to the solution. Seaborn `pairplots` have `plot_kws` that takes as arguments a dictionary of the kind of modifications you would do in a `regplot`. The following line is exactly what I needed:

```
g = sns.pairplot(df, kind='reg', plot_kws={'line_kws':{'color':'red'}, 'scatter_kws': {'alpha': 0.1}})
```

And this is the outcome:

[image]

If you don't do the regression but just the scatter plot (kind='scatter'), within plot keywords you don't have to do the division between line and scatter keywords:

```
g = sns.pairplot(df, kind='scatter', plot_kws={'alpha':0.1})
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with `kind="scatter"`, though : `AttributeError: Unknown property line_kws`.

Comment: This unfortunately also applies the alpha to the legend. Is there any way around that?

Comment: How can also annotate the actual pearson correlation value on each plot?

Comment: @seralouk I am afraid you will have to compute it outside of seaborn and then display it

Comment: for me this worked: `sns.pairplot(df, plot_kws=dict(alpha=0.5))`

Answer (score -4):

Alpha can be set as a keyword argument as so:

```
g = sns.pairplot(df, kind='scatter', alpha=0.1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Seaborn v0.9.0. You need to specify the alpha as a member of (e.g. plot_kws=dict(alpha=0.4) ). See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930250/how-to-change-the-scatter-transparency-in-seaborn-pairplot