# How to change the scatter transparency in Seaborn.pairplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
sns.pairplot(data_new, kind="scatter", hue="location", plot_kws=dict(s=80, edgecolor="white", linewidth=2.5))
```

Hey folks, can someone tell me how to change the scatter transparency(alpha should be 0.3) following my code above?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are already using `plot_kws` to pass in parameters to the plotting function. Therefore, `alpha` is simply another parameter you can add to this dictionary:

```
sns.pairplot(data_new, kind="scatter", hue="location",
              plot_kws=dict(s=80, edgecolor="white", linewidth=2.5, alpha=0.3))
```