# Seaborn catplot transparency customizaton

Tags: python, seaborn

Seaborn comes with a relatively new [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) function. Is there a way to specify the transparency, conform the `alpha` parameter in for example `regplot`? (see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200033/how-to-adjust-transparency-alpha-in-seaborn-pairplot) question).

The following does not work:

```
  sns.catplot(x = 'var1', y = 'var2', data=df, kind='box', plot_kws={ 'scatter_kws': {'alpha': 0.5}})
```

Comment: You can use the color argument.

Comment: Could you illustrate it in the `sns.catplot( color = ...)` function?

Comment: IIRC you can specify the color as a 4-tuple that represent the RBGA values.