# Set transparency in sns.pointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pointplot

I am trying to figure out to add transparency or alpha to `sns.pointplot`. I have a plot that looks like this:

[image: Overlapping horizontal errorbars]

I am trying to add the transparency or alpha to it, but no luck. I know I can set alpha in `sns.kdeplot` but not sure how to do it on `sns.pointplot`.

```
plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q1 = sns.pointplot(df1['Q53Val'][0:191], color='#22b584', dodge = True, errwidth=50, scale = 7.5, plot_kws=dict(alpha=0.3)).set(xlim=0)
q2 = sns.pointplot(df1['Q53Val'][192:], color='#f77f2f', dodge = True , errwidth=50, scale = 7.5, plot_kws=dict(alpha=0.3)).set(xlim=0)
ax.set(ylabel=None)
ax.set(xlabel=None)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0])
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

Comment: Does this question work for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200033/how-to-adjust-transparency-alpha-in-seaborn-pairplot
[alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200033/how-to-adjust-transparency-alpha-in-seaborn-pairplot)

Comment: Hey, Sorry for the fusion. I am referring to sns.pointplot but I tried using alpha but it did not work

Comment: Seaborn uses alpha for the error bands, it doesn't support alpha for the main lines nor the markers.